# How To show ALL text as a default on search in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, aura

I have one datalist where I am getting all account Names and displaying like a dropdown.
I want to add `--ALL--` as a default option
Like currently my compo is like
[image]

but I want to add `--ALL--` As a default option like below

[image]

```
 <label class="slds-form-element__label" style="margin-right: 0.5rem;">Select Account</label>
 <input data-id="inputData" onchange={} required value={accuntName} name="input" list="filterList" placeholder="search Account" class="slds-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
    <datalist data-id="AccountList" id="AccountList" class="">
        <template for:each={accountDeails} for:item='item'>
            <option key={item} value={item}>{item}</option>
        </template>
    </datalist>
```

JS

```
accountDeails()
    .then(result=>{
     if(result){

        this.accountDeails = result;
    }
let listAcc= this.template.querySelector('datalist[data-id="AccountList"]').id;
this.template.querySelector('input[data-id="inputData"]').setAttribute("list", listAcc);
```

Apex

```
@auraEnabled
public static list<string> accountDeails() {
list<account>accList =[select id from account];
list<string> acName = new list<string>();
for(account ac:accList) {
acName.add(ac.Name);
}
return acName;
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that this value should be added to the `datalist` options and as selected `value` for the input.

You can do it in **Apex**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> accountDeails() {
    List<Account> accList =[select Id from Account];
    List<String> acName = new List<String>{'--ALL--'};
    for(Account ac : accList) {
        acName.add(ac.Name);
    }
return acName;
```

in **JS** set `accuntName` to `--ALL--`

```
....
accountDeails()
    .then(result=>{
        if(result){
            this.accountDeails = result;
            this.accuntName = '--ALL--';
        }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add it in your template, if you want to:

```
<datalist data-id="AccountList" id="AccountList" class="">
  <option value="">-- ALL --</option>
  <option for:each={accountDeails} for:item='item' key={item} value={item}>{item}</option>
</datalist>
```

Note that using a `template` isn't required for `for:each` if you don't want to use it (but it's fine if you do).

Comment: thanks for that..but how it will be default .like when i am refreshing the page it should show ALL option as default..but currently when i choose drop down then only i can see ALL option